# stata file C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_1i000002.tmp not found

Tags: stata

I have a question about Stata.
I am running the command `geocode` 
I refer to the *Stata Journal* and execute the following command:

```
geocode, address(resp_street) city(resp_city) state(resp_st) zip(resp_zp)
```

Then, I got an error message:

```
file C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\ST_1i000002.tmp not found
```

Does anyone know what happened to my Stata and how to solve this problem?

Comment: There are several versions of this program. For clarity you should report the results of `which geocode` in an edit of your question. `geocode` needs a temporary file in your filespace. We can't reproduce that with no details of what you are trying to access, but see `help trace` for some debugging commands.

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for your response. The version of gecode I used is dm0053 developed by Adam Ozimek and Daniel Miles. Is this information you are asking? I am not sure I understand what you mean the temporary file in my filespace. Can you provide more detail about this? Thank you for your patient and time.

Comment: `which geocode` in Stata should show you a version number and date. That tag indicates a _Stata Journal_ article, which is quite different. The extension `.tmp` indicates a temporary file created by Stata. I really can't say more; I didn't write this program and I am not familiar with its code.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I think I got your points. You still provide very useful information for me to explore the soluation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you have found a bug in the program. The error message, as Nick Cox explained, comes from Stata's attempt to open a temporary file that it was supposed to have created. It did not, which may have happened for a variety of reasons.

Looking at the source code, I see a number of places where creating such a temporary file may have failed. (To Stata experts, the authors of `geocode` used `capture` without ever trying to parse the returned error code. Palm face.) Most likely, the error happened when `geocode` tried to access a fixed URL at Google `http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=`, which does not seem to be supported any longer.

You can `set trace on` to see where exactly the error happens, and write to the `geocode` authors explaining what the error was. That's as far as you can probably get at this point.

Comment: Stask, thank you for your thorough explanation. You did a great job on Chicago conference. I really enjoy your presentation.